# Formatting MATLAB Output

Tags: matlab, formatting, equation

I am writing a program in MATLAB for an assignment. In the program the user is able to enter the values of a fourth degree polynomial equation. The program shows the equation with the numbers in it, and then it solves the equations for various values for x that the user inputs. My problem is that if the user enters a negative number, the program is not allowed to display the equation with plus a negative (e.g. f(x) = 4x^4 + 3x^3 + 2x^2 + -x + -4). It would need to show f(x) = 4x^4 + 3x^3 + 2x^2 - x - 4.

I've tried using if-statements, and I'm not well acquainted with any advanced way of doing this (my MATLAB knowledge is fairly basic and we're only allowed to use things that we've learned in class unless we have permission to do otherwise). I've attempted to make it to where if the user enters a negative number the sign (which is held in a variable) becomes a minus sign. Of course, this doesn't work, since it just makes the equation display minus a minus. I've thought about if the number entered is negative having it be multiplied by a -1 in the display statement. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: You store the plus in a variable? All you should store for a 4th degree polynomial are the four weights, everything else is implicit. If the weight is positive, write “+ w x^n”, if it is negative, write “- w c^n”.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Symbolic Toolbox? You could use symbolic variables for this. E.g.,

```
syms x
c = [2 -3 4];
f(x) = poly2sym(c,x)
```

[image]